# Is there any tooling to document PLC code per IEC 61131 (formerly IEC 1131)?

Tags: documentation-generator

I'm looking for documentation generator tooling - whether open-source, gratis, or not, for programmable logic controller (PLC) code, i.e. the IEC 61131-3 family of programming languages.

By a documentation generator I mean something that produces documentation according to some templates, like Doxygen or Sphinx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need because I don't know plc much. But you could have a look at **PLC Software Control FPWIN Pro**. Using FPWIN you could print variables, comments etc.. The download link is under the title "Software" at this link:

[FPWIN Pro 7 download page](https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/eu/downloadcenter.htm)

**EDIT:** You could create a virtual printer to save to a file.

[Creating virtual printer on Windows](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/c60d541a-8dfc-4d96-a1f1-d89241d95db9/virtual-lab-how-to-create-a-virtual-printer-for-testing-purpose?forum=winserverprint)

---

[image: FPWIN Pro 7 options dialog]

[image: FPWIN Pro print result]

Comment: I'm looking for a documentation tool where you can document the APIs - whether internal or external. Just dumping the variables etc. doesn't help by itself, even if you can add a "comment" to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mention of a Doxygen adaptation in the [*Generating Automatically the Documentation from PLC Code by D4T3 to Improve the Usability and Life Cycle Management of Software in Automation* paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281440142_Generating_Automatically_the_Documentation_from_PLC_Code_by_D4T3_to_Improve_the_Usability_and_Life_Cycle_Management_of_Software_in_Automation) by Racchetti, Tacconi and Fantuzzi. I couldn't find any source code or products available based on this, though.

Comment: Did you have any success? Maybe contact the authors of that paper?

Comment: @Macke Feel free to do that. I've spent quite a bit of time messing with the PLC environments and came to a conclusion that they are so far behind the times when it comes to good software engineering practice, that any "gains" from "industry tested code" are completely erased by the inability to apply modern tooling to the development process. The PLC purveyors are actively advocating dangerous and outdated development practices, and I'm done dealing with that crap. For what I need, I can get plenty of realtime performance using MicroPython, believe it or not.